# Meaning of Cevelop message "add argument(s) '?' to match 'not_severe_error(?)'"?

Tags: cevelop

I have added to functioning code this:

```
auto not_severe_error(int a_code){return (a_code>=0);}
```

and changed:

```
if(rc>=0)
```

to:

```
if(not_severe_error())
```

What is the meaning of:

> Add argument(s) '?' to match 'not_severe_error(?)'

[image: Screen shot Cevelop with message.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Obenland is correct. In the current release (1.7.1), Cevelop does not yet support return-type deduction.

Since we build on-top of CDT, and CDT has added return-type deduction in its current milestone, it is most likely to be included in the next release (1.8) of Cevelop. I currently cannot provide you with a precise timeline for the 1.8 release, but as far as I am aware it will be later this year (after Eclipse Oxygen and CDT 9.3 are released - which is scheduled for June 28).

The question mark in the signature of the suggestion is the result of Cevelop not being able to fully resolve `not_severe_error()`. Somewhat simplified, the symbol index sees the "overload" taking an int, but because currently functions returning `auto` have an "incomplete type", it cannot be sure if other overloads exist.

Answer (score 0):

`not_severe_error` expects one parameter. You probably wanted to write:

```
if(not_severe_error(rc))
```

---

I think it has something to do with `auto` as return type. When changing this to `bool` the message disappears. Probably a bug with the type system of Cevelop.

Comment: Absolutely.  As a new user of Cevelop,the question is the meaning/purpose for the third blue message.